# Pandas: populating column values with date and time string based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks as follows:

```
created_time                         action_time
2021-03-05T07:18:12.281-0600         2021-03-05T08:32:19.153-0600
2021-03-04T15:34:23.373-0600         2021-03-04T15:37:32.360-0600
2021-03-01T04:57:47.848-0600         2021-03-01T08:37:39.083-0600

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'created_time':['2021-03-05T07:18:12.281-0600', '2021-03-04T15:34:23.373-0600', '2021-03-01T04:57:47.848-0600'],
                  'action_time':['2021-03-05T08:32:19.153-0600', '2021-03-04T15:37:32.360-0600', '2021-03-01T08:37:39.083-0600']})
```

I then create another column which represents the the difference in minutes between these two columns:

```
df['elapsed_time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['action_time']) - pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'])).dt.total_seconds() / 60 

df['elapsed_time']

elapsed_time
74.114533
3.149783
219.853917
```

We assume that "action" can only take place during business hours (which we assume to start 8:30am).

I would like to create another column named `created_time_adjusted`, **which adjusts the `created_time` to 08:30am if the created_time is *before* 08:30am**).

I can parse out the date and time string that I need, as follows:

```
df['elapsed_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time']).dt.date.astype(str) + 'T08:30:00.000-0600'
```

But, this doesn't deal with the conditional.

I'm aware of a few ways that I **might** be able to do this:

```
replace
clip
np.where
loc
```

What is the best (and least hacky) way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your life would be easier if you convert the columns to datetime dtypes from the go. Then, its just a matter of running an apply op on the 'created_time' column.

```
df.created_time = pd.to_datetime(df.created_time)
df.action_time = pd.to_datetime(df.action_time)
df.elapsed_time = df.action_time-df.created_time
time_threshold = pd.to_datetime('08:30').time()
df['created_time_adjusted']=df.created_time.apply(lambda x:
                                                  x.replace(hour=8,minute=30,second=0)
                                                  if x.time()<time_threshold else x)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                      created_time                      action_time            created_time_adjusted
0 2021-03-05 07:18:12.281000-06:00 2021-03-05 08:32:19.153000-06:00 2021-03-05 08:30:00.281000-06:00
1 2021-03-04 15:34:23.373000-06:00 2021-03-04 15:37:32.360000-06:00 2021-03-04 15:34:23.373000-06:00
2 2021-03-01 04:57:47.848000-06:00 2021-03-01 08:37:39.083000-06:00 2021-03-01 08:30:00.848000-06:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['created_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'])#Coerce to datetime
df1=df.set_index(df['created_time']).between_time('00:00:00', '08:30:00', include_end=False)#Isolate earlier than 830 into df
df1['created_time']=df1['created_time'].dt.normalize()+ timedelta(hours=8,minutes=30, seconds=0)#Adjust time
df2=df1.append(df.set_index(df['created_time']).between_time('08:30:00','00:00:00',  include_end=False)).reset_index(drop=True)#Knit before and after 830 together
df2
```